# BroadcastReceiver is not called by alarm

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

There are a lot of related questions and I beleive I've read them all twice or so. For some reason I seem to have tomatoes on my eyes. I do not see the error.

I've got an alarm set up using Alarm manager. (Happy to share more code if required.)

```
   private static String ALARM_ACTION = "de.klecker.BigBen.Alarm";

   private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent() {

      Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getContext(), BigBenAlarm.class);
      alarmIntent.setAction(ALARM_ACTION);
      return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
   }
```

`getContext()` returns a reference to the application.

```
   public static void setAlarmFromNow() {

      AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

      PendingIntent intent = createPendingIntent();

      // First cancel any ongoing alarm
      manager.cancel(intent);

      manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (5 * 1000), intent);

      Log.d("BigBen", "Alarm is set!");

   }
```

The alarm is properly registered. This is an extract of the output of

adb shell dumpsys alarm

```
Batch{2f6ac936 num=1 start=68344020 end=68344020}:
  RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{f8a5037 type 0 when 1453976393037 de.klecker.bigben}
    tag=*walarm*:de.klecker.BigBen.Alarm
    type=0 whenElapsed=+4s155ms when=2016-01-28 11:19:53
    window=-1 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{3df19a4: PendingIntentRecord{18a6130d de.klecker.bigben broadcastIntent}}
```

And it got actually fired. This is an extract from the log:

```
01-28 11:19:53.038 V/AlarmManager(  885): sending alarm {18a6130d type 0 *walarm*:de.klecker.BigBen.Alarm}

01-28 11:19:53.039 V/AlarmManager(  885): done {18a6130d, *walarm*:de.klecker.BigBen.Alarm} [1ms]
```

But the receiver did not get called. This is the receiver class:

```
public class BigBenAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vibrator.vibrate(2000);
      Log.d("BigBen", "Alarm fired!!!");
   }

}
```

Neither the log statement appears on the log, nor does the phone vibrate. (Virbration permission was declared in manifest). I tried toasts and playing sounds and setting a breakpoint, but apparently, the method is never called.

This is how the receiver is registered:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver android:name="de.klecker.bigben.BigBenAlarm">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="de.klecker.BigBen.Alarm"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So which important detail did I miss?

Comment: @MD Apologies. Yes, it is. I'll add that line of code to the question.

Comment: Also remove  `manager.cancel(intent);`

Comment: I'll try removong `manager.cancel(intent);` Although as it is documented, it should not do any harm. On the contrary. The alarm is actually fired, as the log says.

Comment: try to set another option   `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`

Comment: removing `manager.cancel(intent);` does not make a change nor does `setInexactRepeating` make a change. Again, the alarm is properly registered and actually fired. See the log statements.

Comment: Is `Log.d("BigBen", "Alarm fired!!!");` printing in Log?

Comment: @PiyushGupta, no it is not printed to the log. If it was then I would not have any problem at all. It would appear on the log between the lines with "sending alarm" and "done".

Comment: Are you calling from activity

Comment: @PiyushGupta am I calling what exactly from an activity?

Comment: Here are a few things you could try: Replace the last 0 when creating the `PendingIntent` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATR_CURRENT`, Remove the IntentFilter in the Manifest.

Comment: @TR4Android. Thanks. I already removed the filter. I even just tried filters this morning before posting the question here as a final try, because I do believe that it should work without filtering at all. Well, there are lots of sources on SO and others stating that the filter is actually required. 
I'll try the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT although I do not see how that could help as the alarm is actually fired. See the log extact. Anyway, using that flag will prohibit the usage of multiple pending intents within the same app.

Comment: I got it working without a filter so I'm sure it's not required.

Comment: And you can still use multiple pending intents by using different ids.

Comment: And you could try setting `android:enabled="true"` on the receiver in the manifest. I have this though I'm not sure anymore if it was on purpose.

Comment: @TR4Android FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT did not make a change so far. Next I'll try removing the intentFilters. Then I will try again adding enabled="true".

Comment: @TR4Android, removing the IntenFilter did not make a change.

Comment: And finally `enabled="true"`did not make it work either.

Comment: Some debugging thoughts: Add a `Log` statement to output `BigBenAlarm.class` to confirm the full name is what you expect (de.klecker.BigBen.BigBenAlarm).  Try invoking your receiver with a normal broadcast, `Context.sendBroadcast()`, just to see if the simple case works.  `BigBenAlarm` is not declared as an inner class is it?

Comment: [PackageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) might also be helpful to test that your intent resolves to your target receiver.

Comment: @qbix, thanks. Actually it is 'de.klecker.bigben.BigBenAlarm'. I noticed the flaw in the meantime and corrected it without updating the question. Should be fine now but I'll double check with `BigBenAlarm.class`. I have got no inner classes and will try invoking the receiver directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who tried hard. 
And yes, I did have tomatoes on my eyes. Although quite embarassing I leave this in and provide an answer in case that anybody else runs into the same issue.

The big mistake was within the android manifest. The receivers need to be registered within the application tags.

```
AndroidManifest.xml: 
<application
    android:name=".BigBenApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Big Ben"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity android:name=".BigBenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="de.klecker.bigben.BigBenAlarm"
              android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="de.klecker.BigBen.Alarm"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

For some reason I closed the application and then tried to register the receiver.

Comment: `Your issue is as Big as Large Size Tomato or a Pizza`

Comment: I am glad there are no limitations in issue size at SO. The disussion here was very helpful to rule things out and eventually nail it down.